# Excel combo box change data in a cell

Tags: excel

so I'm smashing my head into the wall with a simple task that I can't find the solution to.
I've made a combo box with next 2 words in it: "Yes" , and "No". When I choose 'Yes' I want a cell to be changed to 0. When I choose 'No' I want a cell to be changed to 0.15 .

Would appreciate any type of help..

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't have the Cell Link specified, and referencing that Cell Link.

Right click on the combo-box and click "Format Control..."  Go to the "Control" tab.

- The "Input range:" is what will populate the option in the drop down list.
- The "Cell Link:" is where you specify what output cell will be changed based on the combo-box selection.
- For "Drop down lines:" you should put 2 since you have two options (Yes and No).

Now you will need to use an IF statement to set your desired values.  So if cell B10 was your "Cell Link", use this formula where you desire to show either 0 or 0.15:

```
=IF(B10="Yes", 0, 0.15)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It almost worked, after I applied the IF statement, the value of my cell was changed correctly but once I went back to my Combo Box, and selected 'Yes' the next value was assigned: '1' , if I selected 'No' the next value was assigned: '2'. Where these come from? Thank you for helping appreciate it